# error on command rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

I'm new to railsand learning selenium tool through it.In this process i came across the below steps to do:
In the folder of your choice, execute the following command:

```
git clone http://github.com/wolframarnold/selenium-test-app.git
```

Go to the selenium-test-app folder and run the following:

```
cp ./vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/test/mock_app/config/database.yml ./config/
```

Up to the above command all went fine, but when i run the below command:

```
rake db:migrate"
```

Found this error:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "actionmailer":String
c:/Users/BH/selenium-test-app/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any one please help on this error?

Comment: Try to get your dependencies first, by this command - bundle install. After that, run rake db:migrate. If it won't help you, use rake db:migrate --trace for full error stack trace and show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed some external dependencies as vitaly said, run `bundle install` but remember to restart your web server to pick up those changes. Then run `rake db:migrate`.